# VBA execute full loop

Tags: vba, debugging

instead of going line by line through a

```vb
for 1 = 1 to 60,000
... do something
next i
```

is it possible to execute all this block and then continue the line by line debugging?
thanks,
Marius

Comment: sure... press F9 to insert a breakpoint on the line after the loop. if you are already in the loop, press F5 to continue until you get to the breakpoint.

Comment: Exactly:
-F5=run the whole macro
-F8=step by step
-F9=add/remove a breakpoint in the code, where it will stop